# Function called on viewController close (when application exit)?

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch

I am looking for a function which is called on a `UIViewController` when the application exits.

I tried it out with `viewWillDisappear` and with `applicationWillTerminate` but nothing works.

I want to save my settings from the `UIViewController` in this function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to register for notifications to know when the appropriate calls are made as an app terminates.

```
NSNotificationCenter .defaultCenter() .addObserver(self, selector: Selector("callBack"), name: UIApplicationWillResignActiveNotification, object: nil)
NSNotificationCenter .defaultCenter() .addObserver(self, selector: Selector("callBack"), name: UIApplicationWillTerminateNotification, object: nil)

func callback() {
  // Save your settings
}
```

Remember to remove the observers in `viewWillDisappear:`

```
override func viewWillDisappear(animated: Bool) {
  super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
  NSNotificationCenter .defaultCenter() .removeObserver(self)
}
```

Comment: I have added the code in my viewDidLoad function         NSNotificationCenter .defaultCenter() .addObserver(self, selector: Selector("saveWorkingState"), name: UIApplicationWillResignActiveNotification, object: nil)
        NSNotificationCenter .defaultCenter() .addObserver(self, selector: Selector("saveWorkingState"), name: UIApplicationWillTerminateNotification, object: nil) but the " public func saveWorkingState()" is never called. I tried it out with a Button on which I called the exit function (in the simulator)

Comment: `exit(0)` should not be used to test whether an app is terminated. This will instantly kill the app without any proper shutdown happening. Just press Cmd + Shift + H to trigger a home button press.

Answer (score 3):

Like @Jeff said, but

#### In Swift 3:

```
override func viewDidLoad () {
  super.viewDidLoad()

  NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(suspending), name: NSNotification.Name.UIApplicationWillResignActive, object: nil)
  NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(suspending), name: NSNotification.Name.UIApplicationWillTerminate, object: nil)
}

func suspending () {
  print("suspending...")
}
```

`UIApplicationWillResignActive` happens when the app is swapped out, while
 `UIApplicationWillTerminate` is triggered when exiting, such as when the Home button is pressed.

Answer (score 0):

you can call *deinit* inside the ViewController

```
deinit {
   deleteUnsavedPhotoFromServer()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

## Swift 5.5

#### Use For App Enter Background

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(appResignActiveNotify), name: UIApplication.willResignActiveNotification, object: nil)
        
 @objc func appResignActiveNotify() {
       //called when App enter background
   }
```

#### For App Terminate

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(appTerminateNotify), name: UIApplication.willTerminateNotification, object: nil)
        
  @objc func appTerminateNotify() {
       //called when Terminate
   }
```